# Uploading big dataset into MySql

Tags: mysql, dataset

I have problem inserting data into MySql. The  dataset I'm using is big, its data on cyber attacks. For example the current data I'm working on is has about 25,000 records and every time I create a new schema and insert the data, only 1000 records are down loaded. I have tried so many times, the result is still the same. Please help me, because I have been reading, and it says that a big data set is not a problem for  MySql.

Comment: And how do you think we could know what went wrong without anything else but your question?

Comment: its not a problem with mysql. Maybe its the dataset, or something about requesting the data from the site

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html). Before we went to a true search engine, we used to have to export 3-hourly snapshots which included millions of rows. So we exported data by way of [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html), then did a LOAD DATA INFILE on edge nodes. Took about 15 minutes to load data for the biggest database (5 million+).

Comment: thanks, I will try that. My data is very small compared to yours. Hope ill be able to do it. Will inform you the status.

Answer (score 0):

a very old question, my 2 cents for those who may stumble here.

25,000 records is too small a size for mysql to have any kind of issues. We have hundreds of tables with millions of rows. Unless, say, you are running mysql on a raspberry pi.

The size of input records is not the problem. The two potential reasons I can think of are:

1. You have a "**IGNORE *number* LINES**" option in your LOAD INFILE.
2. Your Select has "**LIMIT 1000**" option. In case you are using some kind of Mysql client program (ex: SqlYog), they have a default limit.